# how can i transform a mysql query "group by statement" result to a json structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select, group-by

i have a query with a group by statement and i want to transform that data in a proper json object

**query:**

```
SELECT c.name, count(u.id) 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN contries AS c ON u.country_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

**expected result:**

```
{canada: {count: 1565}, colombia: {count:15645612}}
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `group by c.name` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a level of aggregation and use [`json_objectagg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) (available starting MySQL 5.7):

```
select json_objectagg(name, js_count) js
from (
    select c.name, json_object('count', count(u.id)) js_count
    from users as u 
    inner join contries as c on u.country_id = c.id 
    group by c.id, c.name
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'name', c.name,
  'count', count(u.id)
)
FROM users as u INNER JOIN contries AS c ON u.country_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

"`select return JSON`",  there are two ways of doing this :

1. use a "hack" - see the db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEz4mZX56Jj7TWRsN91ibX/4),
2. or use one of the new MySQL supplied JSON functions here - which, ironically, appears to be even more of a hack than the hack itself! Only with MySQL! :   (fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEz4mZX56Jj7TWRsN91ibX/4)).